# Order Status is Pending after Paypal Payment

Tags: 7, ubercart, payment-gateways

I created an order with weekly or monthly subscription. User can purchase the subscription only through paypal.

If a user purchase the subscription he redirected to paypal site. After successfully payment the order is created. But the order status showing `pending`. It should be `completed`.

Recurring Module : [UC Recurring Payments and Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring)

Payment Method - Paypal

(Edit) Problem was in Sandbox paypal Account. Api Credential (Password and Signature) was not there. I changed the merchant account Api Credential.

After changed the api credential same problem occured with changed account. What to do?

Comment: We sympathize with you. Now, could you maybe ask a question so someone could answer? Or maybe provide a bit more details, like names of modules you are using?

Comment: By mistake I disabled the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubercart does not make orders completed on it's own. It seems to be a well known problem, already [discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220889/drupal-ubercart-automatically-complete-orders-skipping-pending-status) and [on ubercart.org](http://www.ubercart.org/comment/48599). It seems manually setting up Conditional Actions is a must in most cases.

Comment: But a few days ago It was working well. It updated the status automatically.

Comment: Then tell us what have changed during last few days. And tell us if the site backup made week or two ago works well, if restored to test environment.

Comment: I was working on data migration from last few days and used a module `uc_register_invoice`. I checked it yesterday and it was not working.

Comment: If the backup made before that work works all right, it's a bug in either your workflow, or uc_register_invoice. If it does not, something happened with your server or paypal api coincidentally. You do have backups and test environment, do you?

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I didn't change in that site anything. It was a backup site on which i was trying.

Comment: Please check updated question.

Comment: Sry Guys.. By mistake I disabled the rule. It was my Mistake. :(